# Confusion about css floats in my project

Tags: css

I'm always stuck when it comes to `float`. In my grid project, I want to have my buttons in the left and my table in the middle, like in the shown example. And my footer should be bottom but i don't know for what reason is not `https://codepen.io/coderBoyNaN/pen/wprOMX`. Can anyone help? Exemple of how it should look like, i wanna make it more responsive: `https://codepen.io/Soheevich/pen/VybrOo`.

Comment: You are required to post your markup within your question itself and not a third party site: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just erase `float: left` from `div#menu`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpEXdP

Comment: Why are you answering a question that doesn't supply any markup?